# mysql speed up update statement for copying values between tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables where I am trying to copy values from migrate table to regular table. It seems to take awhile.  (10 minutes for 43k records)

```
UPDATE phppos_sales_items,phppos_sales_items_migrate 
SET 
     phppos_sales_items.subtotal = phppos_sales_items_migrate.subtotal,
     phppos_sales_items.tax = phppos_sales_items_migrate.tax,
     phppos_sales_items.total = phppos_sales_items_migrate.total,
     phppos_sales_items.profit = phppos_sales_items_migrate.profit

WHERE 
phppos_sales_items.sale_id = phppos_sales_items_migrate.sale_id and           
phppos_sales_items.line = phppos_sales_items_migrate.line and      
phppos_sales_items.item_id = phppos_sales_items_migrate.item_id;
```

Migrate Table

```
CREATE TABLE `phppos_sales_items_migrate` (
  `sale_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `line` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subtotal` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profit` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

sales_items

```
 CREATE TABLE `phppos_sales_items` (
  `sale_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rule_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rule_discount` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `serialnumber` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `line` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity_purchased` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `item_cost_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `item_unit_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `regular_item_unit_price_at_time_of_sale` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_percent` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `commission` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `subtotal` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `tax` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `total` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `profit` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sale_id`,`item_id`,`line`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_3` (`rule_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_sales` (`sale_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_price_rules` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

`decimal(23,10)` is excessive, especially for integral values, such as `quantity_purchased`.  Shrinking the datatypes will help speed some.

Use a "multi-table Update" with `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.

Let's see the output from

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM phppos_sales_items         AS i
         JOIN phppos_sales_items_migrate AS m
       ON  i.sale_id = m.sale_id
      and  i.line    = m.line
      and  i.item_id = m.item_id;
```

If you have a new enough version of MySQL, also provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`

Any chance there are new rows in `migrate`?  If so, won't you need `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

43K rows in which table?  How many in the other table?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, adding Index to the Target Table are worth to try.

Since two tables are comparing the three columns for merging it, you might better to adding index to the `phppos_sales_items_migrate` table for  (`sale_id`,`item_id`,`line`) columns.

Good Luck

PS. FYI, adding indexes to the table also take costs for updating and inserting thus minimize to the comparing columns.